# Setting NO COUNT ON in VBA ADODB

Tags: sql, vba, adodb

After hours of frustration I have realized that I have become a victim of [Error Messaging Referencing #Temp Table with ADO-SQLOLEDB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/235340/en-us)

> When you try to create a ADO recordset based on a #Temp table created
>   within a stored procedure called by ADO using the SQLOLEDB provider,
>   you may encounter one of the following error messages...

The solution is to add `SET NOCOUNT ON` to either the Stored Procedures, or to the VBA code when the recordset is open.  At the moment I am stuck with adding it to my VBA code.

The example code that MS gives as a solution is something like:

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "spThatHasTempTable"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 
..


Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
    Set .ActiveConnection = conn
    .Open "SET NOCOUNT ON"
End With

rs.Open cmd, , , , adCmdStoredProc
```

This works for me.  However I feel like that setting `SET NOCOUNT ON` really should be a part of the `Command` object construction, but I can't seem to figure out how to do just that.

So how would I include `SET NOCOUNT ON` when constructing the `Command` object?

Answer (score 0):

Can you combine the SQL? so your command becomes `"set nocount on; select * from table"`?
I know in some situations you can't have multiple commands.

Comment: There is no SQL per se as I am executing a stored procedure, so that ADO is actually constructing it behind the scenes

Comment: change to statement and use `set nocount on; exec procname` then? Though tbh I'm not sure I understand the drive for it to be part of the command?  Unless you want to run second command that needs nocount off?

Comment: Logically the `NOCOUNT ON` belongs with the command and not the recordset